# How to add pattern or write numbers on a cylinder?

Tags: graphics3d

I want to draw several cylinders in Mathematica. In order to distinguish them in a grey-style print, I should write a visible number on or add a different pattern (dotted, lines, stripes, etc.) to each of them. Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
    Graphics3D[
          Table[
           {Cylinder[{{x, y, 0}, {x, y, 1}}], 
           Text[Style[ToString[x/2] <> "," <> ToString[y/2], 24, Gray], 
            {x, y, 1}]},
            {x, 0, 5, 2}, 
            {y, 0, 5, 2}]
            ]
```

Or why not just use a different color on each, and then have a legend?